# Coding that deletes old posts through php or cron task

Tags: php, cron

I am very new and having problems with a website I am creating.  A developer I am not, but I am trying to learn.  Here is my problem, which I have found possible solutions on earlier posts, but unsure what to do.

I am creating a site that a section aggregates certain news articles by keywords which I choose.  The posts come into a post grid by title.  The titles are links back to the original site.  Unfortunately, it has taken me a few months (yes months) working on this site and subdomains.  I am finding posts that were scraped, but have been sitting on my front page for over a month.  I would like to delete or move them somewhere after 2 days.  I have found two items below.  Will one work and if so what do I do with it?  Literally, how and where would I incorporate it?  Thanks so much and sorry for such rudimentary questions.  Elliot

```
delete FROM `wp_posts`
WHERE `post_type` = 'post'
AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), `post_date`) > 2
```

OR

```
$days = 2;
$dir = dirname ( __FILE__ );

$nofiles = 0;

if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
    while (( $file = readdir($handle)) !== false ) {
        if ( $file == '.' || $file == '..' || is_dir($dir.'/'.$file) ) {
            continue;
        }

        if ((time() - filemtime($dir.'/'.$file)) > ($days *172800)) {
            $nofiles++;
            unlink($dir.'/'.$file);
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
    echo "Total files deleted: $nofiles \n";
}
```

Comment: `DATE_DIFF` has 3 params, please check error message, and/or SQL manual.

Comment: Pavel.. thanks I can make that change.  With the change should it do what I am hoping for and if so.... ok, this is very basic, but...... how do I install it?  Thanks for your help.